# Use the AWS phar file in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-web-services, phar

I'm creating a web application, using the Amazon SDK 2.5.2. It uses the modular HMVC approach with codeigniter.

I've successfully used the SDK 1.x up to this point but really want to switch to the newest version.

The site says you could install via `composer` (a complete nightmare in itself; `curl` doesn't work correctly on the server, running commandline php doesn't either. I've tried everything!), via `zip` ( After I upload all the files I have no idea what to do next), `PEAR` (I don't want to go there) and via `Phar`. The last option sounds the best in my situation (apart from `Composer` which, as I said, is not going to work). I have put the `phar` in the `libraries` folder and when requiring it from a normal `PHP` file and then `use`ing it:

```
// Get the complete API
require 'aws.phar';
// Use the API
use Aws\Common\Aws;
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
```

There is no problem. I get to use all the functions and everything just works.

However, when `require`ing from a controller or model and then `use`ing it, codeigniter returns the following error:

```
unexpected 'use' (T_USE)
```

I think this has to do with the HMVC structure or codeigniter in general, but as there is no real documentation on it I'm hoping there is someone here who knows what to do next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use `use` in the global scope, or inside a namespace. You *cannot* declare `use` inside a class, method, function or anything else.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php